# Could not catch raise for this case

Tags: python, exception

I have a re-triable wrapper class in Python which helps other *func* to retry. Let's assume my class is just called *Wrapper*. Here's my rough implementation (not real code):

```
Wrapper:
  while True:
    try:
       func()
    except Exception as e:
       pass
    num_retry--
    if num_try == 0
       raise
```

When I use the wrapper, I do:

```
try:
  // use Wrapper
except Exception as e:
  // handle exception
```

But I found the except part doesn't capture the exception, why? Anything special in Python about raise?

Comment: Which `except`?

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you already captured the exception previously when you indicated that it was ignored with the sentence `pass` into `Wrapper`. Then the exception will not go up to the first `try` since it will be ignored.

Remove the capture of the exepction into `Wrapper`, and only let the capture outside. But the correct is that you should capture the exception into `Wrapper` not outside of him.

Comment: But when num_try is 0, I call 'raise', why it's not captured outside?

Comment: I see that the syntax you use for the raise is incomplete. You can verify the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/errors.html) to use it correctly.
Here is a simple example `raise Exception('I know Python!') `